# Designing a SQL query builder

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, content-management-system

How would you go about to design a query builder for an advanced CMS/sitebuilder?  If I start out by letting the user select affected tables, then all columns which should be displayed, then criteria, sort order and limit results I might have enought info to make querys like:

```
SELECT df.gh, yu.df FROM df, yu WHERE df.id != yu.id AND df.other == yu ORDER BY df.something LIMIT 0,10
```

But what about more complex querys, like sub-querys, joins, unions and the like? What kind of information would I need to collect in order to make a correct assumtion about which type of query to generate?

I'm not asking for code here, it's just I'm stuck in my thinking about how to design the thing, which questions I need to ask the user?

For the simpler type querys, like the one above, it's pretty straight-forward and I have a picture of the flow in my mind - but I guess that I don't have enought knowledge about the other query types to even know what info I need to collect in order to make one.  Any design ideas for how to go about building something like this would be appreciated!

Another question, how important are these "advanced" querys for development?  The CMS thingy I'm working on will also have some type of scripting engine so mayebe I woun't need support for sub-querys, unions, joins and so on if it's always possible to work around any problems using code. What would be the minimum requirements in your opinion?

Anything I produce will of course be open source, so throw any ideas my way - I got some coding to get started on. ;-)

Comment: I would just start by examining the one in Microsoft Access and stealing ideas from it.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I worked with [esperant](http://www.speedware.com/solutions/business_intelligence/query_&_reporting/esperant/). It is a query builder and reporting tool. Esperant allow that user write your own querys, also write it in alike english language. And also has wizards to make querys. That I like of Esperant is that it can simplify a complex query spliting it in several named querys.

When Esperant wizard is invoked, a modal window appears and user can try between several query styles: simple query (select fields from several tables and make condition), having query , combine querys. You can recicle querys to create new ones.

All of this tools have a [semantical layer abstraction](http://www.b-eye-network.co.uk/view/12763) that informs tool about table relations (to be possible do joins).

I have also worked with other OLAP and Reporting tools. At this time with [MS SSAS](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/analysis-services.aspx) and [Tableau Software](http://www.tableausoftware.com/).

Comment: Link is dead.  This one might be better: http://www.freschelegacy.com/en/data-sheets/esperant-query-and-reporting-tool-better-business-decisions
Looks very old though.

Comment: @archangel76 have you installed it? Wow.

Comment: no way. I was just fixing the link.